# Trying to execute ifconfig to get mac address

Tags: php, exec

I am trying to execute

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'
```

My code is here

```
$content = shell_exec("ifconfig eth0 | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'");
echo ($content);
```

I have even tried `exec`.

I am not sure why is it that whenever I execute this command or any other *ifconfig* command it does not work.

*netstat* or *route* work fine, but *ifconfig* never works. Is there a setting I have to change in PHP? I am currently running PHP 5 with save-mode off.

Comment: "Does not work" is no error. What do you expect, what happens, what happens if you remove the grep part?

Comment: Are you sure ifconfig is in your PATH when the code executes?

Comment: @CodeCaster if I remove grep part and try to run ifconfig I also get nothing.       Steve C What is PATH for executing code?

Comment: Nothing? What happens if you run "ifconfig eth0" from the command line?

Comment: PATH is set by the web server.  You can give path to a program explicitly by doing "/sbin/ifconfig" instead of just "ifconfig", for example.

Comment: @SteveC Thank you very much, just by adding /sbin/ the command has worked. Why is it that ifconfig required the extension though?

Answer (score 0):

Any of the commands you mentioned work as a normal user (`netstat` and `route`). `ifconfig` normally needs root permissions on Linux servers.
But, there's a way around:

http://itechlog.com/linux/2009/01/17/opensuse-run-ifconfig-as-user/